# No inserta la tabla Matrícula

Tags: php

```
<?php

 session_start();

 $cn=mysql_connect('localhost','root','mysql');
                 mysql_select_db("muninet");
                 $rs = mysql_query(" select max(IdMatricula) as codigo from TMatricula");
                 $n = mysql_affected_rows($cn);
                 if($n >= 0){

                 $xcodigo = mysql_result($rs,0,"codigo");
                 $xcodigo =substr($xcodigo,4,6);
                 $xcodigo = $xcodigo + 1;
                 $codigo ="M".substr("00000".$xcodigo,-5,5);
                 }

  $IdeUsuario=$_SESSION['cod'];
  $Fecha=$_POST['textfecha'];
  $IdeAlumno=$_POST['textAlucod'];
  $Precio=$_POST['textPrecio'];
  $Boleta=$_POST['textNBoleta'];

/*echo $codigo ."<br>";
echo $IdeUsuario ."<br>";
echo $Fecha ."<br>";
echo $IdeAlumno ."<br>";
echo $Precio ."<br>";
echo $Boleta ."<br>";*/




require_once('conexion_Boleta.php');

$mysql = new connection();
$conexion = $mysql->get_connection();


$datos = array("IdMatricula" => $codigo,"Fecha" => $Fecha,"IdeUsuario" => $IdeUsuario,"IdeAlumno" => $IdeUsuario);
$statement = $conexion->prepare("CALL insertar_Matricula(?,?,?,?)");
$statement->bind_param("ssss", $datos["IdMatricula"],$datos["Fecha"],$datos["IdeUsuario"],$datos["IdeAlumno"]);
$statement->execute();
$statement->close();

?>
```

Comment: Hola Fernando! ¿Te muestra algún error? ¿Probaste ejecutar el procedimiento almacenado directamente en la base de datos? Para descartar que sea un error de sintaxis en la consulta.

Comment: Estás mezclando código de dos API distintas, por un lado se ve código de la API `mysql_`,  la cual ha sido declarada obsoleta,  y  por otro lado hay código de `mysqli` ... ¿a qué se debe que mezcles código? Deberías usar en todo `mysqli`.